# How to create a common function for show form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I usually used the following code to show form:

```
frmEmployeeManage em = null;
private void ShowEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (em == null || em.IsDisposed)
        {
            em = new frmEmployeeManage();
            em.MdiParent = this;
            em.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            em.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            em.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            em.Activate();
        }
    }
```

Now I want to write a function for showing form. The following code I don't know how to pass a form class as parameter to the function.

```
class CommonService
{
  public static void ShowFrom(Form frmChild, Form frmParent)
  {
    if (frmChild == null || frmParent.IsDisposed)
    {
        frmChild = new Form(); // How passing the form class here?
        frmChild.MdiParent = frmParent;
        frmChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frmChild.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        frmParent.Activate();
    }
  }
}
```

Finally I use the show form function like the following example:

```
frmEmployeeManage em = null;
CommonService.ShowForm(frmEmployee, this);
```

Comment: What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to use a `ref` parameter:

```
  public static void ShowFrom<T>(ref T frmChild, Form frmParent) where T : Form, new()
  {
    if (frmChild == null || frmParent.IsDisposed)
    {
        frmChild = new T(); // How passing the form class here?
        frmChild.MdiParent = frmParent;
        frmChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frmChild.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        frmParent.Activate();
    }
  }
```

And call it like this:

```
frmEmployeeManage em = null;
CommonService.ShowForm(ref em, this);
```

`ref` allows you to change the value of the parameter in a method, and the changes are reflected on the variable passed in as well.